# Select all in pandas where column equals value and all other columns are blank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame containing permissions for roles of each user, e.g.

| function/role | role1_permissions | role2_permissions | role3_permissions | role4_permissions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| can create | Y | Y | N | Y |
| can update | Y | Y | Y | N |
| can delete | Y | N | Y | N |

I want to be able to select from the DataFrame where column role1_permissions = Y, where all other columns contain N.

(I can't install any other packages such as pandassql to do this)

I have currently only selected where column role1_permissions = Y:

```
filtered_permissions = permissions.loc[permissions[role1_permissions] == 'Y']
```

How do I select where all other columns equal N? Without specifying each column like this:

```
filtered_permissions = permissions.loc[permissions[role1_permissions] == 'Y'] & permissions.loc[permissions[role2_permissions] == 'N'] & permissions.loc[permissions[role3_permissions] == 'N'] ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Chain 2 conditions - for compare `role1_permissions` for `Y`, then select all columns with `_permissions` by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), remove first column, test for `N` if all values per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (permissions)
  function/role role1_permissions role2_permissions role3_permissions  \
0    can create                 Y                 Y                 N   
1    can update                 Y                 Y                 Y   
2    can delete                 Y                 N                 N   

  role4_permissions  
0                 Y  
1                 N  
2                 N  

mask = (permissions.role1_permissions.eq('Y') & 
        permissions.filter(like='_permissions')
                   .drop('role1_permissions', 1).eq('N').all(axis=1))

filtered_permissions = permissions[mask]
print (filtered_permissions)
  function/role role1_permissions role2_permissions role3_permissions  \
2    can delete                 Y                 N                 N   

  role4_permissions  
2                 N
```